# jaxws ri unmarshal exception

Tags: jax-ws

**I am using jax ws ri implementation for webservices, if in include extra < or > tag in request to my webservice, i m getting following error**

S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   
      
         S:Server
         javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character (CTRL-CHAR, code 10) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [12,2]]
         
            
               javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character (CTRL-CHAR, code 10) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [12,2]]

****Is there any way that my webservice handles such exceptions and throw some meaningful message to my client****